# WPF TreeView with checkboxes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview, checkbox

After a lot of searching, I have not found any solution for the following problem.
I need a treeview control with "checkboxed" treeview items and the `CheckedItems` property for convenient data binding (for example, treeview of folders' structure, when user checks folders, the size of checked folders is displayed in a textbox).

By the way, I have read the article [«Working with Checkboxes in the WPF TreeView», Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithCheckBoxes.aspx), but the "IsChecked" approach is not appropriate in my case because I need to bind `CheckedItems` as a collection.

I would appreciate any help!

[image]

The image link has been attached. I want the listbox to be data bound to `CheckedItems` property of `CheckTreeView`. Does anybody know how to implement the generic `CheckTreeView` with possible binding to `CheckedItems` collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**
Finally got around to update the CheckBoxTreeView with the missing features. The CheckBoxTreeViewLibrary source can be [downloaded here](http://www.mediafire.com/?cbq2qpmcg84b2y8)

- Adds the CheckedItems property
- CheckedItems is an `ObservableCollection<T>` where T is the interal type of ItemsSource
- CheckedItems supports two-way Binding to source
- If a CheckBoxTreeViewItem hasn't been generated yet (not expanded to) then the source for it won't be in the CheckedItems collection until it has been generated

The Control can be used just like a regular TreeView. To add two-way binding for the IsChecked property, the CheckBoxTreeViewItemStyle.xaml ResourceDictionary must be merged. e.g.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/CheckBoxTreeViewLibrary;component/Themes/CheckBoxTreeViewItemStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then the ItemContainerStyle can be used like this

```
<cbt:CheckBoxTreeView ...>
    <cbt:CheckBoxTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type cbt:CheckBoxTreeViewItem}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type cbt:CheckBoxTreeViewItem}}">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
            <!-- additional Setters, Triggers etc. -->
        </Style>
    </cbt:CheckBoxTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</cbt:CheckBoxTreeView>
```

**CheckBoxTreeView.cs**

```
namespace CheckBoxTreeViewLibrary
{
    [StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ItemContainerStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(CheckBoxTreeViewItem))]
    public class CheckBoxTreeView : TreeView
    {
        public static DependencyProperty CheckedItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CheckedItems",
                                        typeof(IList),
                                        typeof(CheckBoxTreeView));

        private RoutedEventHandler Checked_EventHandler;
        private RoutedEventHandler Unchecked_EventHandler;

        public CheckBoxTreeView()
            : base()
        {
            Checked_EventHandler = new RoutedEventHandler(checkBoxTreeViewItem_Checked);
            Unchecked_EventHandler = new RoutedEventHandler(checkBoxTreeViewItem_Unchecked);

            DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd =
                DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(CheckBoxTreeView.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(CheckBoxTreeView));
            if (dpd != null)
            {
                dpd.AddValueChanged(this, ItemsSourceChanged);
            }
        }
        void ItemsSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Type type = ItemsSource.GetType();
            if (ItemsSource is IList)
            {
                Type listType = typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(type.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
                CheckedItems = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
            }
        }

        internal void OnNewContainer(CheckBoxTreeViewItem newContainer)
        {
            newContainer.Checked -= Checked_EventHandler;
            newContainer.Unchecked -= Unchecked_EventHandler;
            newContainer.Checked += Checked_EventHandler;
            newContainer.Unchecked += Unchecked_EventHandler;
        }

        protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
        {
            CheckBoxTreeViewItem checkBoxTreeViewItem = new CheckBoxTreeViewItem();
            OnNewContainer(checkBoxTreeViewItem);
            return checkBoxTreeViewItem;
        }

        void checkBoxTreeViewItem_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBoxTreeViewItem checkBoxTreeViewItem = sender as CheckBoxTreeViewItem;

            Action action = () =>
            {
                var checkedItem = checkBoxTreeViewItem.Header;
                CheckedItems.Add(checkedItem);
            };
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
        }

        void checkBoxTreeViewItem_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBoxTreeViewItem checkBoxTreeViewItem = sender as CheckBoxTreeViewItem;
            Action action = () =>
            {
                var uncheckedItem = checkBoxTreeViewItem.Header;
                CheckedItems.Remove(uncheckedItem);
            };
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
        }

        public IList CheckedItems
        {
            get { return (IList)base.GetValue(CheckedItemsProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(CheckedItemsProperty, value); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CheckBoxTreeViewItem.cs**

```
namespace CheckBoxTreeViewLibrary
{
    [StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ItemContainerStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(CheckBoxTreeViewItem))]
    public class CheckBoxTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
    {
        public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Checked",
            RoutingStrategy.Direct,
            typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
            typeof(CheckBoxTreeViewItem));

        public static readonly RoutedEvent UncheckedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Unchecked",
            RoutingStrategy.Direct,
            typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
            typeof(CheckBoxTreeViewItem));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked",
                                        typeof(bool),
                                        typeof(CheckBoxTreeViewItem),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
                                                                      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                                                      CheckedPropertyChanged));

        private static void CheckedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBoxTreeViewItem checkBoxTreeViewItem = (CheckBoxTreeViewItem)source;
            if (checkBoxTreeViewItem.IsChecked == true)
            {
                checkBoxTreeViewItem.OnChecked(new RoutedEventArgs(CheckedEvent, checkBoxTreeViewItem));
            }
            else
            {
                checkBoxTreeViewItem.OnUnchecked(new RoutedEventArgs(UncheckedEvent, checkBoxTreeViewItem));
            }
        }

        public CheckBoxTreeViewItem()
            : base()
        {
        }

        protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
        {
            PropertyInfo parentTreeViewPi = typeof(TreeViewItem).GetProperty("ParentTreeView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            CheckBoxTreeView parentCheckBoxTreeView = parentTreeViewPi.GetValue(this, null) as CheckBoxTreeView;
            CheckBoxTreeViewItem checkBoxTreeViewItem = new CheckBoxTreeViewItem();
            parentCheckBoxTreeView.OnNewContainer(checkBoxTreeViewItem);
            return checkBoxTreeViewItem;
        }

        [Category("Behavior")]
        public event RoutedEventHandler Checked
        {
            add
            {
                AddHandler(CheckedEvent, value);
            }
            remove
            {
                RemoveHandler(CheckedEvent, value);
            }
        }
        [Category("Behavior")]
        public event RoutedEventHandler Unchecked
        {
            add
            {
                AddHandler(UncheckedEvent, value);
            }
            remove
            {
                RemoveHandler(UncheckedEvent, value);
            }
        }

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return (bool)base.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
        }

        protected virtual void OnChecked(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.RaiseEvent(e);
        }
        protected virtual void OnUnchecked(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.RaiseEvent(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**CheckBoxTreeViewItemStyle.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:cti="clr-namespace:CheckBoxTreeViewLibrary">
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <PathGeometry x:Key="TreeArrow" Figures="M0,0 L0,6 L6,0 z"/>
    <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Height="16" Padding="5,5,5,5" Width="16">
                        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Data="{StaticResource TreeArrow}" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#FF989898">
                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                        </Path>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF1BBBFA"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF595959"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF262626"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type cti:CheckBoxTreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cti:CheckBoxTreeViewItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="15" Width="Auto"/>
                            <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>-->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="15"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"/>
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Margin="0,2,4,0" x:Name="PART_CheckedCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Nice code! Thanks! But after binding ItemsSource to Customers(List<Customer>) and CheckedItems to SelectedCustomers (ObservableCollection<Customer>()), a null reference exception is thrown. If change SelectedCustomers property type ObservableCollection<object>(), there no exception is thrown. How to solve this problem?

Comment: By the way, how to provide two-way data binding for the CheckedItems property?

Comment: @Serge: Updated my answer, after a little more than a month but better late then never :) I don't know if you still need a CheckBoxTreeView but my updated answer should include the features that the last one was missing

Comment: Thats a very interesting piece of code and approuch. I have been trying it out and almost works as expected. I expect however that the CheckedItems property reflects the selection made in the gui. So if a treeviewitem is checked it would be added. I have 4 weeks experience with WPF now so I could be missing something obvious. Should I specify something extra in the markup?

Comment: Hi. Great example. I've bound the CheckedItems to both the TreeView and a ListBox via two way binding. However if the ListBox deletes an entry in CheckedItem, the TreeView does not reflect the change. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: <ListBox Grid.Column="0" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding CheckedItems, Mode=TwoWay}"  
 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxDataTemplate}" 
 ItemsPanel="{StaticResource listBoxItemsPanel}"/>
<controls:CheckBoxTreeView 
 ItemsSource="{Binding FirstLevel}" 
 CheckedItems="{Binding CheckedItems, Mode=TwoWay}" 
 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource treeViewDataTemplate}" 
 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource treeViewContainerStyle}"/>

Comment: Figured it out. I was missing the IsChecked Setter in my XAML